# Trying to Understand whats wrong with my bubble Sort Method

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

Im Not Sure why my code wont work.All of them print the same values instead of sorting them.
The output doesnt change and the arrays seems unsorted still.Any Ideas how i can fix this?I would like to learn why.

```
    void BSort::BubbleSort()
{   int temp =0;
     for(int index = 0; index < sizes; index++){
        for(int index2 = 0; index2 < sizes-1; index2++ ){
            if(Array1[index2] > Array1[index2+1]){
                 temp = Array1[index2];
                 Array1[index2] = Array1[index2+1];
                 Array1[index2+1] = temp;           }
        }
     }


}

/*************************************************************************/
//---------------------------  BubbleSort2( )  --------------------------//
/*************************************************************************/


void BSort::BubbleSort2()
{ 
     int temp =0;
     for(int index = 0; index < sizes-1; index++){
        for(int index2 = sizes-1; index2 > index; index2--){
            if( Array2[index2] < Array2[index2-1]){
                 temp = Array2[index2];
                 Array2[index2] = Array2[index2-1];
                 Array2[index2-1] = temp;           
        }
        }
     }
}

/*************************************************************************/
//-----------------------------  CombSort( )  ---------------------------//
/*************************************************************************/


void BSort::CombSort() {
int temp = 0;   
int tempsize =sizes;
int index2;
while((tempsize = int(tempsize/1.3)) >1){
    for(int index = sizes-1; index >= tempsize; index--){
        index2 = index-tempsize;
        if(Array3[index] < Array3[index2]){
            temp = Array3[index];
            Array3[index] = Array3[index2];
            Array3[index2] = temp;
        }   
    }
    bool testcase = true;
    for(int in = 0; in < sizes; in++){
        for(int in2 =sizes-1,testcase = false; in2 > in; in2--){
            if(Array3[in2] < Array3[in2-1])
            { temp = Array3[in2];
                Array3[in2] = Array3[in2-1];
                Array3[in2-1] = temp;
                testcase = true;
            }
        }
    }
}



}
```

Main File

```
#include<iostream>



#include<cstdlib>

#include "BSort.h"
using namespace std;


int main(void)
{


       int a[] = {-2, 88, 6, -1, 10, 15, 3, 12, -11, 9, 33, 21, 4, 7, 45, 55, 62, 18, 0, 20};


        BSort S(a,20);


        cout << endl << " Display Array elements before sorting";
        S.DisplayListElements();

        // Calling bubble sort
        S.BubbleSort();
        S.BubbleSort2();
        S.CombSort();

        cout << endl << endl << " Display Array elements Increasing order After BubbleSort";
        S.DisplayListElements();



        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the code to how you call `BubbleSort` functions ?

Comment: Even assuming you get it to work, you bubble sort still has a major problem: it's a bubble sort.

Comment: Its a homework assignment.And ill post the main file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..  Basically after each iteration you need to run inner loop one less then outer variable... mainly because it is already sorted

```
 void BSort::BubbleSort()
{   int temp =0;
     for(int index = 0; index < sizes; index++){
        for(int index2 = 0; index2 < sizes-index; index2++ ){
            if(Array1[index2] > Array1[index2+1]){
                 temp = Array1[index2];
                 Array1[index2] = Array1[index2+1];
                 Array1[index2+1] = temp;           }
        }
     }


}
```